# No CREATE_TIMEDATE column, can I still export records inserted within last 24 hours?

Tags: sql-server

A database was designed almost 10 years ago, now I may need to export records inserted from the last 24 hours. Back then, the table design did not include CREATE_TIMEDATE col for these tables.

Is there any luck that database servers (in this case SQL Server 2005), have a system hidden TIMEDATE attribute for all table records so I can export all records within 24 hours?

Or is my only solution is to save last primary key id at midnight and then 23.99 hours later, export from last primary key id to current primary key id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 there is no hidden column for the date something was added to the table.

the best solution would be to add a new DATETIME column to the tables you are looking to export the last 24 hours if this is to be an ongoing process (you could put an insert trigger on the table to make sure the column is populated).  Entries from before you started tracking the creation date can remain NULL or be set to something like '1900-01-01' (the "0" date in SQL Server).

If changes to the table are not permitted then the only option is to query the table at midnight and then again at midnight the next day (a SQL Agent job would be the best way to accomplish that).  However this only works if the primary key is always increasing in some manner (Identity column for example).  Otherwise you wont know what range you need to select, (IE if your primary key is email for some reason you wont know when a record was inserted based on the sequence).

I would also suggest a table to hold those results from the query every 24 hours so if you need to rerun the export for a specific day you would have the information you needed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the old backup might be the fastest way. Another possibility would be to examine the transaction log (in case you're using full recovery mode). But it is very hard to get the records out of the log without the help of external products.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the table has an identity column. (Otherwise, how would you know which was the 'last' primary key ID?)

Your idea is spot on, i would just modify it slightly and write the greatest exported ID somewhere at the end of your export procedure. Then simply export anything greater than that in your next run. (Or maybe i misunderstood and that's exactly hat you're planning to do anyway.)

If there is no identity column, you'd have to copy the whole primary key column to a log table, export everything not logged and then copy exported keys to the log table again.